# how to read one complete row in the CSV

Tags: python, csv, sikuli

I'm trying to read a complete row which is containing two three points in my CSV document. but it is reading first line of the row and come back to the script. Please help me to come out from the issue.

My script is:

```
import csv

# Enter file name details
file = input("Enter File name")
if (file == ""):
    popup("No file name given")
    exit(0)
# Enter Row number details
Row = int(input("Enter a row number"))
if(Row == ""):
    popup("no row number given")
    exit(0)
# main Function call
def lineFromCSV(file, Row):
    data = csv.reader(open(file), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for i in range(Row+1) :
        Row = data.next()
    return Row

def extractColInfo(temp):
    for i in range(7):
        tt[i] = temp[i]
        popup (str(tt[i]))

temp = lineFromCSV(file, Row)

popup( ', '.join(temp))
popup ("Done")
```

My csv is:

```
Sl No   DO-229D STP ID  Scenario    Simulator   Dump
1   2.1.1.2 (b)
    2.1.1.3.1 (b)   STP-GPSBL-007   gpsb028 Spirent Iono_corrections_from_gps
2   2.1.1.2 (c )
    2.1.1.3.1 (c )  STP-GPSBL-008   gpsb028 Spirent Iono_corrections_from_waas[sv].validity
                                                                                                    No_of_svs_for_iono_corrections
3   2.1.1.2 (d)
    2.1.1.3.1 (d)
    2.1.1.2 (g) STP-GPSBL-009   gpsb028 Spirent Tropospheric_corrections [var_sv]
```

Comment: Since your "rows" span multiple lines, you can't use Python's csv module to extract an entire record. The csv module reader takes any line break (`\r\n`, `\n`, `\r`) as the row terminator. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator).

Comment: You might need to clean up your csv file before opening it in csv reader. It looks pretty messed up to me.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/264354

Answer (score 1):

You can get the next row like this by iterating over the data.

```
data = csv.reader(open(file), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in data:
   // code you want to write
```

And then try to manipulate the things according to your need.

Comment: If above solution helped you then you can tick it and up vote it :)